# Changing tree view selection color in QT with a stylesheet

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to change the color of the selection of the tree elements. I have been able to successfully change most of the color with

```
QWidget:item:selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

but to the left of the selected element there is the default blue highlighting as well and would like to change this. If you have any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
QTreeView::branch:selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code from [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview):

```
QTreeView::branch  {
        background: palette(base);
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item  {
        background: cyan;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item  {
        background: red;
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item  {
        background: blue;
}

QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings  {
        background: pink;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed  {
        background: gray;
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
        background: magenta;
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings  {
        background: green;
}
```

Comment: This is close but this causes the arrows to disappear on the tree